# passing a vector member (struct) to a function

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I am getting errors on following lines of code.I am trying to pass vector  p's element p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3] to the function distance.

```
typedef struct {
     long long x,y;
} point; 

long long distance (point A,point B)
{
    int d1 = A.x - B.x ;
    int d2 = A.y - B.y ;
    long long d = d1 * d1 + d2 *d2 ;
    return d ;
}

 //in main function I declared vector <point> p and took input and then,
    x1 = distance (p[0],p[1]) ; // this line is causing error
    x2 = distance (p[1],p[2]) ; // this line is causing error
    x3 = distance (p[2],p[3]) ; // this line is causing error
    x4 = distance (p[3],p[0]) ; // this line is causing error
```

errors generated :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:66:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
                 from d.cpp:19:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation of ‘std::iterator_traits<point>’:
d.cpp:83:27:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:166:53: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct point’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:167:53: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct point’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:168:53: error: no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘struct point’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:169:53: error: no type named ‘pointer’ in ‘struct point’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:170:53: error: no type named ‘reference’ in ‘struct point’
```

Help is needed.

Answer (score 8):

It's most likely because you have

```
using namespace std;
```

in your code. This makes the compiler think you are referencing [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) instead of your function.

The obvious solution, and what I really recommend, is to stop with `using namespace std;` in your code. In the meantime you could try calling your function using the global scope, like

```
x1 = ::distance (p[0],p[1]);
```

Comment: yes , It is working now.I have never seen std::distance before.

Comment: @aroup It is very important to stress how disruptive `using namespace std` can be. You should try no tot use it *anywhere*, except probably in very small scopes, in which case it yields no advantage anyway. Unfortunately, whenever I say it I get into big fights with others who believe it is perfectly safe to use it indiscriminately in implementation files. It is not, as you have found out.